# Adding color codes to tooltip for indicators

Tags: highcharts

Consider this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/1pbhtbwo/2/

with these plot options:

```
plotOptions: {
  macd: {                
              macdLine: {
                styles: {
                  lineColor: "blue",
                  lineWidth: 1
                }
              },

              signalLine: {
                styles: {
                  lineColor: "red",
                  width: 1
                }
              },
              marker: {
                fillColor: "lightblue"
                // width:1,
              }

            },
  }
```

On the tooltip, only MACD has the color code. It is hard for the user  to know which line is **Signal** and which line is **Value**.

[image]

How can I add a color for **Value**, **Signal** and **Histogram** on the tooltip to make it easy to distinguish them? Ideally, this is what I need:

[image]

I found [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/SRfW6/55/) that is closer to what I want  by creating a separate series for each sub-series of the indicator, but apparently that plugin is [not supported anymore](https://github.com/laff/technical-indicators).

This is much more needed for other indicators like `ichimoku cloud`. It's really hard to know which line is which:

[image]

Comment: hi check this http://jsfiddle.net/ay8ka6gd/

Answer (score 0):

This format string defines properly colored dots:

```
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> <b> {series.name}</b><br/>' +
      '<span style="color:{series.options.macdLine.styles.lineColor}">\u25CF</span>Value: {point.MACD}<br/>' +
      '<span style="color:{series.options.signalLine.styles.lineColor}">\u25CF</span>Signal: {point.signal}<br/>' +
      '<span style="color:{series.options.marker.fillColor}">\u25CF</span>Histogram: {point.y}<br/>'
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w2v8v2r1/

I used references to series options to get the colors used on the graph.

The original `tooltip.pointFormat` value can be found in core code of MACD indicator: https://code.highcharts.com/stock/indicators/macd.src.js